# C# VS2017 debug library code not working, with symbols loaded and Just My Code disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm going a bit crazy trying to get the VS2017 debugger to step into some library code. The symbols are loaded for the library:

`'MyApp.UI.TestApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MyApp.UI.TestApp.exe): Loaded 'Y:\Projects\app\MyApp.UI.TestApp\bin\Debug\IdentityModel.OidcClient.dll'. Symbols loaded.`

I have `Enable Just My Code` switched off:

[image]

But alas, when I hit F11 to step into the library code, the debugger thinks for a couple of seconds, and then steps over.

Any ideas most gratefully received!